# Can std::search_n be called with a count of 0?

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

Can `std::search_n` be called "safely" with a `count` of 0?  Specifically, is code like the following valid?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const int test[7] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    const int *const location = std::search_n(test, test + 7, 0, 8);
    if (location == test) {
        std::puts("Found it at the beginning!");
    }
}
```

I would expect this code to reach the `std::puts` statement, and most descriptions of `std::search_n` seem to imply that it will.  However, most sample implementations that I'm finding *won't*.  What sayeth the standard?

Comment: I do not know what the standard says, but if you look at the libstdc++ implementation (http://cs.brown.edu/~jwicks/libstdc++/html_user/stl__algo_8h-source.html) you will see that whenever the size <=0 it will return first always. And they claim: "Everything defined by the ISO C++ Standard is within namespace std." So that is what the standard should say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The specification of `std::search_n` is (§25.2.13 [alg.search]/p4-7):

> ```
> template<class ForwardIterator, class Size, class T,
> class BinaryPredicate>
> ForwardIterator
> search_n(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Size count,
> const T& value, BinaryPredicate pred);
> ```
>
> 4 *Requires*: The type `Size` shall be convertible to integral type
>   (4.7, 12.3).
>
> 5 *Effects*: Finds a subsequence of equal values in a sequence.
>
> 6 *Returns*: The first iterator `i` in the range `[first,last-count)` such that for every non-negative integer `n` less than `count` the
>   following corresponding conditions hold: `*(i + n) == value, pred(*(i + n),value) != false`. Returns `last` if no such iterator is found.
>
> 7 *Complexity*: At most `last - first` applications of the
>   corresponding predicate.

When `count <= 0`, there is no non-negative integer `n` less than `count`, so the condition "for every<sup>*</sup> non-negative integer `n` less than `count` ..." is always true<sup>**</sup>, and so it should return the first iterator in range - which is `first`. Note that the spec implies that you are not allowed to pass a negative `count` if `last-count` isn't well-defined, but nothing in the spec prevents `count` from having a value of zero.

All standard library implementations I tested (libstdc++, libc++, MSVC) print the message.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>This used to be "for any...". [LWG issue 2150](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2150) changed the wording here to clarify the intended meaning.</sub>

<sub><sup>**</sup>The statement "for every x in S, p" is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) if S is an empty set.</sub>

Comment: point-of-interest: boost 1.51 implementation of search_n does a std::find for value before checking for a sequence of "count" matches.  When that fails it returns last.  I'm not saying that's how it _should_ work.  Just that that's how it _does_ work. (and yes, I know boost != std)

Comment: @DaleWilson Interesting. Sounds like it needs a bug report.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with this interpretation.  I was confused because the sample implementations at [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search_n](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search_n) and [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search_n/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search_n/) lack this behavior.  I guess they're buggy.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen Yeah, these sample implementations may well be wrong in corner cases.

Comment: I've gone ahead and emailed www.cplusplus.com about this.  I'm considering correcting the code on en.cppreference.com, though I'd rather be 100% sure before making that change.

Comment: What a lovely question. It is a bit strange for a `search` function to return an iterator to an element that fails the predicate... So it is conceivable that this is not what the C++ committee *meant*. (I would expect a footnote at least.) But T.C. is right that this is quite unambiguously what the standard *says*.